# Suppressing warnings from `rvm install`

Tags: rvm

Given this `.rvmrc`

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p290
```

Every time I `cd` I get

```
Already installed ruby-1.9.2-p290.
To reinstall use:

  rvm reinstall 1.9.2-p290
```

I only want to see output if rvm installs a ruby.  I do not want to see the above help message every time I `cd.`  Is there a `--quiet` flag?

PS: If only the above error message was written to stderr, then I could just use output redirection ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks somehow nonsense - `.rvmrc` is to `use` ruby, if you want to make sure that ruby is installed use:

```
rvm use --install 1.9.2
```

I removed the `-p290` - because ruby already moved forward, new security patches were applied, and it's basically good idea to use the latest patchlevel.

If you were using gemset then your command should look like:

```
rvm --create --install use 1.9.2@gemset
```

Which additionally to installing ruby would also create gemset if nonexisting